# Multiple file upload with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, multiple-file-upload

I'm new to `reactjs` and I'm trying to upload multiple file upload. I can able to store the files in state component as array . But When I'm passing the data to axios post method, it gives me the list of files as `[object FileList]` . And I couldn't able to traverse through that files to store . Even I tried multiple methods to upload multiple files like 'react-Dropzone`. But didn't help.

My react Code .

```js
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({ file: event.target.files })
}

async handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  let res = await this.uploadFile(this.state.file);
}

async uploadFile(File){
  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('image', File)
  axios.post(UPLOAD_ENDPOINT, formData, {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  }).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <input type="file" id="file" multiple name="file" onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-info"> Update File </button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The

```
event.target.files
```

Will give you a file list, and to append it to form data use the following code.

```
const files = event.target.files;

for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    formData.append(`images[${i}]`, files[i])
}
```

On the server side you will get all the images from *'images'* key of request object/variable

Comment: Nice and simple. `files` is a `const` perhaps though.

Answer (score 5):

```
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { 
    formdata.append(`images[${i}]`, {
                    uri: pathOfFile,
                    name: fileName.jpg,
                    type: mimeType(eg. "image/jpeg")
    });
}
```