# How to select all images at once in react-js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to select all images

```
state = {
    file: null
}
handleFile(e) {
    let file = e.target.files
    this.setState({ file: file })
    console.log('handle file:', file)
}
```

if i use index like this, then i can only upload single image

```
let file = e.target.files[0]
```

but i want to select all index at once and upload it ! i can upload multiple images with POSTMAN but not react.

this is the index which i want to select all at once

[image]

i want to select all index and use it in within

```
let file = e.target.files  <----here
```

not like this !

```
let file = e.target.files[0] or [1] or [2] ....
```

how to select all index at once ? thank you in advance :)

Comment: What does it mean "select all index at once", an array of files is a "selection" for you? Did you read about `#Array.map`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Im sorry for inconvenience. im asking how to select all those index without just choosing single index of that images? in another words how to select all images with those indexes?

Answer (score 0):

`e.target.files` is just an array, `.forEach` should work well

You could also use array in the state

```
state = {
    files: []
}
handleFile(e) {
    let files = e.target.files
    let filesUploading = [];
    files.forEach((file, idx) => {
        filesUploading.push({
            id: idx,
            name: file.name,
            file: file
        })
    })
    this.setState({ files: filesUploading })
}
```

For the actual upload, check answers here
[Multiple file upload with reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59451364/multiple-file-upload-with-reactjs)

Comment: Thankyou for the response but forEach throws error !